# $n^2$ is a multiple of $3$, then $n$ is a multiple of $3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Consider the following statement:

> For all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, if $n^2$ is a multiple of 3, then $n$ is a multiple of $3$.

1. Prove this statement by the contrapositive.

So my answer for question 1 would be:

For all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, if $n^2$ is not a multiple of $3$, then $n$ is not a multiple of $3$.

Consider the following proof:

Proof:

(1) Let $n^2$ be a multiple of $3$.

(2) Then $n^2 = 3q$ for some integer $q$.

(3) By uniqueness of prime factorization, $3$ is in the prime factorization of $n^2$.

(4) Suppose $3$ is not in the prime factorization of $n$ and let $p_1,\ldots,p_s$ be the prime decomposition of $n$.

(5) Then $n^2=p_1p_1\ldots p_sp_s$ but $3\neq p_i$ for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,s\}$, contradiction. QED

2a. What is the contradiction that arises in the proof?

2b. Why the uniqueness of prime factorization allows us to claim in (3) that $3$ is in the prime factorization of $n^2$?

3. Write a direct proof of the theorem.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: The contrapositive is that if $n$ is not a multiple of $3$ then $n^2$ is not a multiple of $3$

Comment: You are confusing *contrapositive* with *converse*.

Comment: @mweiss No, the converse is "If $n$ is a multiple of $3$, then $n^2$ is a multiple of $3$".

Comment: @user236182 Sorry, I ought to have said "inverse".  But the inverse and the converse are logically equivalent.